# Site stalled after implementation of backbone router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a single-page application. Data are provided by a node server ; front is coded in javascript. Initially I had one unique url for my whole site (despite the fact that I had many screens, each one generated in js in predefined div). But I've been asked to generate one url for each screen, so I decided to use Backbone (last version) router to do so (Implementation can be found below).

The fact is that since I implemented this router, sometimes :

- the site takes a long long time to load. Something like 1 minute. I've taken a look on Chrome Developer Tool, Network section. It told me my localhost was "Stalled"
- some images are not loaded

Generally it goes better after a new refresh, but not always.

Any idea about the reason why this happens ?

```
var BaseRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

    language : undefined,

    routes: {
        '' : 'home',
        ... // All my routes
        },
        _bindRoutes: function() {
        var me = this;

        if (this.language) {
            _.each(_.keys(this.routes), function(key) {
                me.routes[me.language + '/' + key] = me.routes[key];
                delete me.routes[key];
            });
        }

        // Call native _bindRoutes method.
        Backbone.Router.prototype._bindRoutes.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    home: function () {
        navservice.loadScreen({page : 'home'});
    },
    ... // all routes implementations   
});

var EnglishRouter = BaseRouter.extend({
    language: 'en'
});

new BaseRouter();
new EnglishRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: Did you mean "backbone router" instead of "bootstrap router" in title?

Comment: Right ! Fixed, thanks.